# Using regex in java to extract a string between two words in html syntax

Tags: java, html, regex

I have a json feed that feeds html that is used to populate the calendar, I need to retrieve some of the information from it. For example title, time and location. I wanted to use regex to get content between

```
<span class=\"title\">
```

and

```
<\/span><br/><b>
```

and I am trying to use this code

```
for(int i = 0; i < json.length();  i++)
{
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json.getJSONObject(i));
    System.out.println(object.getNames(object));

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(<span class=\"title\">)(.+?)(<\\/span>)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(json.get(0).toString());
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
```

But it doesn't seem to do the job... I have tried multiple ittoriations and tried researching examples online, but I am not sure if I am doing something wrong in the regex syntax. Help would be appreciated.

```
{"hoverContent":"<b>Title: <\/b><span class=\"title\">Accounting Awareness<\/span><br/><b>Time: <\/b><span class=\"time\">5:30 PM - 6:30 PM<br/><b>Location: <\/b><span class=\"location\">1185 Grainger Hall<\/span><br/><b>Description: <\/b><br/><span class=\"description\">Information from Kristen Fuhremann, Director of Professional Programs in Accounting and Q&A from a panel of current and former students who will share their experiences in the accounting program. Panel includes a grad of the IMAcc program currently in law school, a candidate for the IMAcc program who studied abroad, an accounting and finance double major, and an IMAcc student who is also a TA for AIS 100. Casual Attire is appropriate.<br />Contact: Natalie Dickson, <a href=\"mailto:ndickson@wisc.edu\">ndickson@wisc.edu<\/a><\/span><br/>","title":"Accounting Awareness","start":"2013-09-30 17:30:00","allDay":false,"itemId":"2356754a-8178-4afd-b4cf-7f5f5ce89868","end":"2013-09-30 18:30:00"}
```

null

Comment: is everything on one line? the "." character in regexp stops matching at the end of the line

Comment: Yes, everything is on the same line, at least it should be a unbroken String that contains what I look for.   
and as of "." characters, should I just run a replace of "." with for example ","? as I dont care for the description and I think that is the only place where I would encounter a period.

Comment: i think you should try ajb's answer

Answer (score 1):

`m.group(0)` always returns the *entire* string that matches the regex.  It looks like you want to return a particular group, so you need to use `m.group(1)` to get the text that matches the first group, `m.group(2)` for the second group, and so on.  In this regex:

```
"(?i)(<span class=\"title\">)(.+?)(<\\/span>)"
```

anything in parentheses, except for things that begin with `(?`, counts as a group, so the portion in `(.+?)` is the second capture group, and you can try retrieving it with `m.group(2)`.  In this case, there's no need to put the `<span` stuff in parentheses, so you could say

```
"(?i)<span class=\"title\">(.+?)<\\/span>"
```

and now use `m.group(1)` to get at the first (and only) capture group.

Comment: it seems that I still get this error

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
 at eventDownload.downloadAndProcess.main(downloadAndProcess.java:57)

Comment: Also, does it matter that there are more /span> tags? Would it match with the next /span> tag it encounters? or would it just pick the last one in the string?

Comment: Please try saving `json.get(0).toString()` in a variable and then printing the variable before using it in `p.matcher`.  If it looks like what you've shown us above, _with backslashes before the quote marks_, then you've got a problem because your regex isn't looking for the backslashes.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be the same. How would I add or remove backslashes? I could run through and replace all of the odd characters with white spaces? Because technically I dont need them?

Comment: What's the type of `json`?  There are probably other methods you could use, besides `toString`, to return the *real* string value.  But without knowing just what `json` is (and what JSON library you're using), it's hard for me to tell.

Comment: here is the json http://bus.wisc.edu/ajax/events/getEvents.aspx?c=%7b19AD61E3-BF23-40CE-B798-A9077C89EA28%7d&start=1380430800&end=1384063200&_=1382447922134

and I am using 

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

I currently removed all of the special characters out of the String. It might be more intensive, but it seems to provide a temporary solution

Answer (score 1):

Using regexp to parse something is not really a good idea from design standpoint.
I would personally just wrap the content in a fake tag and parse it using XML parser. There will be overhead, but you don't use regexp to parse JSON, right? Why not do the same for XML?

Comment: You mean to add root tags? No, you just add them to source string and then parse. String source = "<fakeroot>" + json.get(0).toString() +"</fakeroot>"; parser.parse(source);

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex with `DOTALL` mode, also avoid redundant escaping:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?si)<span class=\"title\">(.+?)</span>");
```

Comment: I still get the same error when trying dotall mode
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
 at eventDownload.downloadAndProcess.main(downloadAndProcess.java:57)

Comment: Use it as: `if (m.find()) System.out.println(m.group(1)); else System.out.println("didn't match!");`

Comment: Now I just get didn't match 20 times :(

Comment: For that you need a while loop as `while (m.find()) {System.out.println(m.group(1));}`